# MySQL time between different rows as an aggregate

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

This is my first post, so please forgive me for any formatting errors.

I need to find the time between each row of data for a large number of users, and then take the average of those times as a function of time. I know how to to do the latter part, I just don't know how to find the time differences between rows.

For example, I can generate this output very easily (for all users sequentially, just using 'John' as an example):

`User   order   time
 John   13      2013-10-31 22:35:19
 John   12      2013-10-18 23:16:50
 John   11      2012-12-07 00:38:34
 John   10      2012-06-10 02:19:14
 John   9       2010-07-02 00:55:54
 John   8       2009-12-20 23:43:41
 John   7       2009-12-20 01:14:32
 John   6       2009-12-18 15:12:40
 John   5       2009-12-13 00:38:38
 John   4       2009-12-12 16:00:13
 John   3       2009-12-12 14:50:18
 John   2       2009-12-11 18:41:15
 John   1       2009-12-04 03:12:06`

But, what I need to find out how to do is create this:

`User   order   time                   timeDiff
 John   13      2013-10-31 22:35:19    13 
 John   12      2013-10-18 23:16:50    300
 John   11      2012-12-07 00:38:34    170
 John   10      2012-06-10 02:19:14    ...
 John   9       2010-07-02 00:55:54    ...
 John   8       2009-12-20 23:43:41    ...
 John   7       2009-12-20 01:14:32    ...
 John   6       2009-12-18 15:12:40    ...
 John   5       2009-12-13 00:38:38    ...
 John   4       2009-12-12 16:00:13    ...
 John   3       2009-12-12 14:50:18    ...
 John   2       2009-12-11 18:41:15    ...
 John   1       2009-12-04 03:12:06    NULL`

This is easily done in excel, but I need the grouping properties for users + dates in order to do some analysis.

All help appreciated!!

Comment: What have you tried, where does it fail? Do you have to do this all in one SQL statement in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Select current.time - previous.time As TimeDiff
From   UserTable current Join
       UserTable previous On current.User = pervious.User And current.Order - 1 = previous.Order
Where current.User = 'John'
```

That should get you the time differences.
You said you knew how to get the average from there.

Comment: this will not work for multiple users. I have a lot of users to look at together :-(

Comment: Why does this not work on multiple users?  Besides the where clause

Comment: Users can have different numbers of orders. for example my order range goes from 1-50+.

 `UserTable previous On current.User = pervious.User And current.Order - 1 = current.Previous`

wouldn't do well.

Comment: You're saying the orders aren't sequential?

Comment: Yes, sorry for confusing response. Order_ids are stored sequentially but not for users. A more realistic representation of the data would have something like 
1st order: 73620
2nd order: 90291
3rd order: 100188.... etc

Comment: Instead of "current.Order - 1" use "(Select Max(Order) Where User = current.User And Order < current.Order)"

Comment: Though at that point with a subquery on every row there's no need to do the join

Comment: Woo! This worked! I got the previous order_ids for every order. Didn't think of a subquery. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, it's easy in Excel. Referring to relative rows in SQL is pretty hard, especially in MySQL.

You have to use server-side variables to establish "state", so you can remember previous values. e.g.

```
SET prev := null;
SELECT User, Order, time, IF(@prev IS NOT NULL, time - @prev, null), @prev := time;
```

It gets even harder since you're doing this for multiple users, and will have to add extra code to detect when the user changes.

For this kind of thing, you're better off doing the calcs in client-side code. Which means just do:

```
   SELECT User, Order, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)
   ...
   ORDER BY User, Order
```

and then you can feed those timestamps directly to PHP's time system for formatting/calculations.